# Could not find method apply() for arguments

Tags: android

I have followed many solutions just to get this to run and have wound up here, but do not know what else to do.

How can I configure this project to run?

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    //兼容Android6.0系统所需，如果这句话报错，可在dependencies标签下使用compile 'cn.bmob.android:http-legacy:1.0'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.htq.baidu.com.htq.baidu.coolnote"

        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

    sourceSets {

        main() {

            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {

        ignoreWarnings true
        //lint 遇到 error 时继续 构建

        abortOnError false
        //build release 版本 时 开启lint 检测

        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // 防止在发布的时候出现因MissingTranslation导致Build Failed!

        disable 'MissingTranslation'

    }
}

dependencies {
 
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'

    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'

    compile 'cn.bmob.android:http-legacy:1.0'

    compile 'cn.bmob.android:bmob-sdk:3.4.7-aar'

    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'

    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.1'

}
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

**setting.gradle**

```
include ':app'
```

**local.properties:**

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\sdk
```

**gradle.propertes:**

```
#Project-wide Gradle settings.


# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
   
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit

# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html
#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip
```

I installed them in C:\Users\lwy.gradle\wrapper\dists:

[image]

Comment: I am running my project but the error appears below:                     Error:(1, 0) Could not find method apply() for arguments [{plugin=com.android.application}] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:D:\AndroidStudioProjects\Android EvernoteDemo\YingBeautyNote-master\CoolNote\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Remove *apply plugin: 'groovy'* from build.gradle and try

Comment: I commented codes of apply plugin: 'groovy'and Sync Project with Gradle Files,but the error still exits.

Comment: Can you post your Top-level build file!! cause I did just run this app, it has no errors.

Comment: Copy content of your root build.gradle. Delete your root build.gradle.Create a new build.gradle .Paste the content.New ->Import Project.

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this problem! Here is my may:

1.copy the contetn of  "build.gradle",then delete the "build.gradle";

2.create a new build.gradle and paste the previous content to this "build.gradle"

That's all !

Comment: This works, because if you recovered your build.gradle from git or another external source,generated in another platform than your original one, i.e. linux->windows, then AS seems to not understand the format of the file.  Your solution works!

Comment: this helps me, thanks! on the other hand, GRADLE is too painful, troubleshooting is just like fishing or gambling...

Answer (score 0):

It happens when u save the file as a unicode format. So copy the contents in other file and delete the older one.

Comment: Be more specific, please.

Answer (score 0):

as for me , change the file encoding from `UTF-8 BOM` to `UTF-8`, it solve my problem.